# How to invoke method after another method?

Tags: java, reflection

Let's say that I have the following code:

```
Method myMethod = Entry.class.getDeclaredMethod("get" + criteria);
entries.get(index).getPort();
```

I'd like to replace the getPort method with the reflected method "myMethod". How can I invoke a reflected method after another method? (entries.get(index) in this case)

It's probably a really simple question, but I've searched everywhere and didn't really find an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From the documentation:](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/methodInvocation.html:)

> Reflection provides a means for invoking methods on a class. Typically, this would only be necessary if it is not possible to cast an instance of the class to the desired type in non-reflective code. Methods are invoked with java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(). The first argument is the object instance on which this particular method is to be invoked. (If the method is static, the first argument should be null.) Subsequent arguments are the method's parameters. If the underlying method throws an exception, it will be wrapped by an java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException. The method's original exception may be retrieved using the exception chaining mechanism's InvocationTargetException.getCause() method.

In your case:

```
myMethod.invoke(entries.get(index), null);
```